# Do two lines dividing an area into four equal pieces intersect at the centroid of this area?

Tags: calculus, geometry

Do two lines dividing an area into four equal pieces intersect at the centroid of this area? I was wondering when I tried the  Plumb Line Method to find the centroid. Can someone help prove or disprove this? Thanks! I suppose this topic can be related to Mean Value Theorem?

Answer (score 2):

No.
The plumb line does not necessarily divide an object into two pieces of equal area (which does not make sense anyway for three-dimensional objects. Consider a T-shape where the vertical and the horizontal bar are made of the same number $n$ of squares. If the equal-area assumption were true, the plumb line obtained from hanging this shape at the lower left corner of the top par, say, would have to cut off exactly between the two bars. But instead it goes through the center of gravity, which is some way into the "vertical" bar. (It *would* be on that sepqration line if we took the top bar, rotatated it by 90 degrees and used it to prolong the other bar, which takes mass away from the separation line).

[image]

Back with the first part of the question, this implies in converese that two lines partitioning a shape into four equal pieces need not intersect in the centroid:
[image]

Comment: I did not say that plumb line divides that area into four equal pieces. May be you over-emphasized that point?

Comment: @TerrenceLiao The plumb line does go throug the centgroid though. On the other hand, my T is partitioned into four pieces of equal area by two lines: its axis of symmetry, and the separation line between the two bars. Ther intersection is not the centroid.

Comment: if you hang the T with the point being the midpoint of the top bar. wouldn't that vertical line going from there go through the centroid?

Comment: oh thank you! Mind telling me which software u used to make the diagram? tikz?